# FileType field in Entity edit form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a user entity. At registration, a file is required. 
When I edit this user entity, I want to be able to see the uploaded file and modify it.

I have this form :

```
$builder->add('email', EmailType::class  , ['label' => 'Adresse mail']);
$builder->add('photo', FileType::class);
```

Controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProfilTutoreFormType::class, $user)
```

Entity :

```
 /**
 * @var string
 */
protected $email;

 /**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $photo;
```

Email field is populated with user's email but photo field stays blank.

Comment: You can use something like $photoUpload in your entity, without Column  annotation, so it wont go to DB. So you will have $photo for current file and $photoUpload for uploading new one. So you can $builder->add('photo', TextType::class); $builder->add('photoUpload', FileType::class); . The another option is to have some DTO above your entity, which is considered as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

First you must copy the file to the system. You should then save the new path to the database. Examine the example here https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: The real problem is that when I go to the edit form, the file linked to the user doesn't appear in the photo field so I can't submit the form because it's blank.

Comment: You can only upload with FileType. You need to use different actions for the change. You have to delete and reload the old file with ajax. Here is a smilar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488108/symfony-file-upload-in-edit-form

Comment: I tried that but I have a validation constraint on the photo field to avoid it to be blank at registration. So when I submit the form, it's not valid and doesn't save modifications.

Comment: When creating a form to edit an already persisted item, the file form type still expects a File instance. As the persisted entity now contains only the relative file path, you first have to concatenate the configured upload path with the stored filename and create a new File class: 

$product->setBrochure(
    new File($this->getParameter('brochures_directory').'/'.$product->getBrochure())
);

Comment: Details are available on the link.

Comment: You should try to use to separate forms and combine them as form collection (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). First form should contain the file upload and should trigger an ajax-request to upload the file. The surrounding form for the user entity should use an submit button and use your mentioned validation constraints. Hope that helps ...